# A primarily opinion-based question is not conside a very low quality?

Tags: support, flagging

First of all I am not criticizing the work of the moderators, I would only learn to use the flags correctly.

I flags this question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/183844/28275 as ***very low quality*** but:

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

And when I go to see the question it is ***put on hold*** as primarily opinion-based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *very low quality* flag for questions is described as:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

A question that is primary opinion-based doesn't necessarily need to be deleted since it is salvageable: It is enough the OP removes that part that makes it subjective, and asks an objective question.

I would rather use that flag for low quality closed questions that cannot be salvaged or have never been edited from the OP in a way to raise their quality. (This means that an edit that changes *i have this problem* in *I have this problem*, or merely adds a link, doesn't count as useful edit.)
For answers, I would use it for non-sense answers like the following one.

> dfgdfgdfg etyerthe erhrjhsrjrstjrjrsjhtsrtjh.